# Como configurar MySQL para múltiplas conexões?

Tags: mysql, sql, banco-de-dados, sql-server, servidor

Olá,
  Possuo um cliente com 3 pontos de venda, 1 escritório e 1 servidor. Tal servidor é MySql. Quando no escritório é realizada uma determinada rotina de exportação, é executada uma query que demora um tempo a ser executada. Com isso os 3 pontos de vendas acabam com o sistema congelado pelo fato do servidor estar executando determinada query. É possível configurar o MySql para múltiplas consultas ? para não ter este problema ao executar tal rotina.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

MySQL tal como outros serviços (SQL Server, Oracle, etc), tal como acabaste por explicar na tua descrição, permite multiplas consultas. Ou seja, o motor de base de dados recebe as coneções com o pedidos e estes são processados em fila, pela ordem de chegada, inclusive os mais demorados. Existe forma de melhorar, podes analisar [aqui](https://docs.microsoft.com/pt-br/sql/relational-databases/query-processing-architecture-guide?view=sql-server-2017) técnicas que existem, mas já lá vamos.
Vamos separar o problema em partes, queres poder correr rotinas de elevado consumo de CPU, RAM e tempo quando os postos de venda estão a utilizar? Se sim, terás de rever o servidor onde está alojado o motor de MySQL (+RAM, +CPU, +Disco-SSD), mas antes disso, terás de rever as queries para serem otimizadas, por vezes uma query mal feita aumenta o tempo de execução de uma consulta para horas, quando deveria demorar segundos. Outra alternativa seria reveres a tua arquitetura, e as consultas pesadas deveriam ser executadas durante um periodo que não afete as vendas e estes dados deveria ser guardados num armazem de dados separado da base de dados operacionais, podes ainda particionar os teus dados. Em suma, existem muitas formas de resolver o teu problema, mas só com mais detalhes sobre toda a arquitetura, consegues ajuda mais concreta.

Comment: Obrigado pelo retorno. Já havia encontrado o problema. Realmente havia uma Query aqui que estava demorando 7 minutos. Verifiquei que não havia index criados e após cria-los a query passou a demorar nem 2 segundos. Obrigado pela atenção.